# C# WPF Convert StrokeCollection to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have stored StrokeCollection in bytes. After convert back to StrokeCollection I want StrokeCollection tranfer to imagesource for image.

```
    private byte[] strokeCollections;

    public void UpdateImage()
    {
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(strokeCollection))
        {
            //converted back to StrokeCollection
            StrokeCollection strokes = new StrokeCollection(stream);
            //Set image control source to strokes image
            DrawingImg.Source = ---.
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library which extends the `StrokeCollection` class to help with these kind of problems. You can find it here: [InkSharp](https://github.com/MichelMichels/InkSharp).

Compile the library and add the dll to your project. Use the `InkSharp.Drawing` class and the function `ToImageSource()`. You can also convert it to a `BitMap` and a `byte` array.